# how do I get to /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/CONNECTION_NAME

Tags: xubuntu, network-manager

I'm new to Ubuntu.

How do I get to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/CONNECTION_NAME` and edit it? I cant find it.

Comment: It's rarely necessary to edit such files - what are you trying to do, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

`CONNECTION_NAME` is a placeholder. It's meant to be replaced with the name of the connection you are trying to edit.

Since you haven't said where you got that or what you're actually trying to do, that's all I can give you.

Answer (score 0):

Open a Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

`gksudo thunar /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`

and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Type your password (you won't get any visual feedback) and again <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This will open a file manager window (Thunar in the case of Xubuntu) with root permissions, so **be cautious**, which contains the configuration for every network connection that this system has ever connected to. Double click the file you need, to edit.

The reason I used `gksu` is because only root has edit permissions, in case you want to modify or restore connection configuration files.

CONNECTION_NAME is a placeholder and can be the name of the connection that interests you most.