# how can i open the files in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections?

Tags: network-manager, thunar

i want to see what are the passwords to the wifi connections that i have used, but i don't know how to open these files. tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815155/how-do-i-get-to-etc-networkmanager-system-connections-connection-name), but i don't have thunar installed apparently. i know i can install it easily using apt-get, but i really have no idea what it is or what filetype is those files. would be glad if anyone could help, as you may have guessed I'm very new to the linux world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` are simple text files and you can view them using `cat` or edit them with any text editor. But you must use `sudo` or administrator password to do so.

To open a file `tt` in that folder, I'd use this command

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/tt
```

Comment: that is what i tried, now i understand i just forgot to escape the whitespaces... thank you, and sorry for the trouble.